# How to sum values in a column based on day of the week in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, duration

I have a Spreadsheet with duration values in one column, and date values in another.

I want to sum duration values based on a particular day of the week... eg, in the example screenshot, the first and last dates are Friday. So I want a formula that would add the duration values from the corresponding cells... a total of `17:00`

[image: Spreadsheet Example]

I've tried a formula like this. But this doesn't work.

`=SUMIF(D:D, CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(),2), "Fri") , A:A)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
=sumproduct(weekday(A:A)=6,D:D)
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=TEXT(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(WEEKDAY(A:A, 11), 5, D:D)), "[h]:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: This does work, but the accepted solution is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an easy way because I'm noob at Google Sheets, but try with array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(D1:D3;WEEKDAY(A1:A3;2);5))
```

Using it as array formula, I got this:

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

### One approach to do this is the following:

1. In column E put the weekday values. Use `WEEKDAY()` function which depending on your setting will make Friday any integer between 1-7. If using default Friday will be "6".
2. Use the `SUMIF()` function. Eg.`=sumif(E:E,"=6",D:D)`
3. Make sure the cell where your `SUMIF()` formula resides, also has a *duration* number format.